# Figaro Gem and Missing `secret_key_base` for 'development' environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, development-environment, secret-key

I'm having difficulty getting the figaro gem configured in my app - here's what I have:

**The error I'm getting**

> Internal Server Error
>
> Missing `secret_key_base` for 'development' environment, set this
>   value in `config/secrets.yml` WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.1.2/2014-05-08) at
>   localhost:3000

**gemfile**

```
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

gem 'figaro'

gem 'flickraw'
```

**application.yml**

```
FlickRaw.api_key: 00000000000etc
FlickRaw.shared_secret: 0000000000etc

development:
  secret_key_base: 0000000000etc

test:
  secret_key_base: 0000000000etc
```

**secrets.yml**
(I added the env variable to see if that would fix it .. it doesn't make a difference)

```
development:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV['secret_key_base'] %>

test:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV['secret_key_base'] %>

# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

I'm grateful in advance for any help ... clearly I'm not implementing this correctly.
here's a link to figaro's docs: https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro

Comment: ENV variables should always be all uppercase, and `secret_key_base` should be 128 chars generated with `rake secret`

Comment: Also, I think your `application.yml` is poorly formed. It should be only YAML (shift over development and test to column zero). The `FlickRaw` code should either not be used, or put in an initializer.

Comment: @Unixmonkey, thanks - I just substituted the 0s' for the secret_key_base to avoid making it public here. Also, development and test are in column 0 in my file ... I just messed up the formatting here - I've edited it.

Comment: The top 2 lines in `application.yml` (FlickRaw.*) are not valid there.

Comment: Thanks! It works ... I replaced the '.' with and underscore for FlickRaw.

Answer (score 1):

It was a typo in the FlickRaw API information. I changes "FlickRaw.api_key:" to "FlickRaw_api_key".